# Esse loop de Javascript está derrubando meu navegador. Alguma idéia do motivo?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Estou resolvendo o seguinte challenge do coderbyte.com:

> Using the JavaScript language, have the function RunLength(str) take
>   the str parameter being passed and return a compressed version of the
>   string using the Run-length encoding algorithm. This algorithm works
>   by taking the occurrence of each repeating character and outputting
>   that number along with a single character of the repeating sequence.
>   For example: "wwwggopp" would return 3w2g1o2p. The string will not
>   contain any numbers, punctuation, or symbols.

Pra fazer o algoritmo de RunLength, escrevi o código a seguir:

```
function RunLength(str) { 

   str = str.split(""); 

   var counter = 1;

   for (var i=1; i<=str.length; i++) {

            if (str[i] === str[i-1]) {
                counter ++;
            } else {
                str.splice(i-1, counter-1, counter.toString());
                counter = 1;
            }   

   }

   return str

}
```

A idéia era inserir com splice a variável counter, que conta quantas vezes uma letra foi repetida, após cada uma das letras repetidas, e retirar as ocorrências da letra repetida.

Comment: A sua pergunta parece ter vindo truncada.

Comment: Não entendi. Como assim trincada?

Comment: Tr**u**ncada. “Sei que a manipulação de counter está …” não tem um predicado.

Comment: Corrigido! Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já dizerem era o problema do contador sempre incrementar o que deixava o loop "infinito"

Mudei o algoritmo para utilizar expressões regulares

```
function RunLength(str) {
    var r = '';
    while (str.length > 0) {
        var current = new RegExp(str[0] + '+' );
        var length = str.match(current).toString().split('').length;
        r += length.toString() + str.match(current)[0][0];
        str = str.replace(str.match( current )[0], '');
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: O que o seu código retorna para a string `"aba"`?

Comment: não, retorna o que o algoritmo pede.

Comment: A resposta para `"aba"` deveria ser `"1a1b1a"`; seu programa retorna `"2a1b"`.

Answer (score 6):

Isto ocorre por que a cada loop ele pega o valor de `str.length` novamente, mas a cada loop o `length` do `str` é atualizado e provavelmente sempre aumenta quando usa `str.splice`.

Recomendo que defina uma variável com o `str.length`, então se o loop nunca termina (loop infinito) por que o valor de `length` sempre aumenta o navegador congela.

Como setar a variável:

```js
function RunLength(str) { 

   str = str.split(""); 

   var counter = 1;

   for (var i = 1, strLen=str.length; i <= strLen; i++) {

            if (str[i] === str[i-1]) {
                counter++;
            } else {
                str.splice(i-1, counter-1, counter.toString());
                counter = 1;
            }   

   }

   return str

}

function testCase(str) {
    document.getElementById("mostrar").innerHTML = RunLength(str).join("");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testCase('wwwoopjj')">Testar wwwoopjj</button>
<button onclick="testCase('wwwggopp')">Testar wwwggopp</button>
<div id="mostrar"></div>
```

Note que o código anterior não apresenta o resultado esperado pelo seu algorítimo, ele era apenas para explicar como evitar o congelamento do navegador devido ao loop infinito, para "compactar" as strings com repetição, você pode usar algo como (baseado em [SOpt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/66395/74436)):

```js
function RunLength(str) {
    if (typeof str !== "string") {
        return "";
    }

    var builder = "";

    var count = 1;
    var prev = str[0];
    var current;

    for (var i = 1, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        current = str[i];
        if (current === prev) {
            count++;
        } else {
            builder += count + "" + prev;
            count = 1;
        }
        prev = current;
    }
    builder += count + "" + prev;
    return builder;
}

function testCase(str) {
    document.getElementById("mostrar").innerHTML = RunLength(str);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testCase('wwwoopjj')">Testar wwwoopjj</button>
<button onclick="testCase('wwwggopp')">Testar wwwggopp</button>
<div id="mostrar"></div>
```

Comment: O problema é que esse código continua não funcionando, certo? Digo, seria necessária alguma correção tipo `i += counter.toString()` imediatamente depois to `str.splice`, e ainda assim o código vai descartar o último _run_ da string.

Comment: @ctgPi Não havia percebido, me concentrei em responder o problema do provável congelamento, vou testar obrigado.

Comment: Sim, por isso o +1 (e de qualquer forma você respondeu exatamente o que foi perguntado).

Comment: Agora que você não altera `str`, o `j` ou não é mais necessário ou deveria ter um nome melhor, tipo `strLength`, se você o está guardando pra economizar o acesso ao atributo.

Comment: @ctgPi Obrigado, já editei, também usei o `typeof` para verificar se é uma string.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fiz uma variável strLen, como vc sugeriu, e agora ele está apontando `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` :(

Comment: @Kvera testei ambos códigos e não acontece o tal erro, talvez você tenha copiado ou apagado algo, ou trocado os nomes das variaveis. Note que o segundo código o algorítimo funciona, o primeiro código era apenas para explicar o motivo do congelamento. Eu editei a resposta, veja que ambos códigos tem botões com o texto "► Executar trecho de código", teste os dois por favor.

Answer (score 4):

Apesar do @GuilhermeNascimento ter falado o seu problema, do método `splice` torna seu loop infinito, vou postar minha solução:

```
function RunLength(str) { 

   str = str.split(""); 
   var strRetorno = "";
   var counter = 1;

   for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
       if (str[i] != str[i+1]) {
            strRetorno += (counter) + str[i];
            counter = 1;
       } else {
            counter ++;
       }   

   }

   return strRetorno;

}

RunLength("wwwggopp");
```

> 3w2g1o2p

Comment: `i == str.length` não é sempre falso?

Comment: Verdade @ctgPi é que eu tinha começado por uma lógica e mudei

Comment: @ctgPi Corrigido e obrigado :)